# What is the optimal batch size for teradata upload

Tags: java, teradata

I am trying to find out what it the optimal batch size for teradata uploads.

I read some article about the optimal batch size . [One](http://developer.teradata.com/connectivity/articles/speed-up-your-jdbcodbc-applications) of them states that `To get top-notch performance, you need to use a batch size of roughly 50,000 to 100,000` rows

However, i have seen people saying that their batch included up to a million of rows .

---

The number of columns could differ and it could be a very heavy 100 rows and 1000 columns dataset .

So , is there any optimal batch size in terms of Megabytes ? How many Megabytes are optimal

So far in my application i am using 200 Megabytes of data set as a maximum batch regardless of how many rows it includes . But i am not sure about whether it is optimal .

Comment: no idea what teradata is but if it involves data sending over the wire then the batch size should correlate with socket transmission buffer size

Comment: Depends on protocol. Depends on hardware. Depends on whether the upload is the bottleneck rather than than the software on either end. Depends on whether you're running single-threaded or multi-threaded on either end. Depends on... Basically, you've got a massively underspecified question; as posed there is no single answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use as much as possible, in fact 50,000 to 100,000 should be the **minimum** recommended size.

The maximum size is only restricted by the available heap size in your JVM.